# Splunk integration with Hadoop

Tags: integration, splunk, mapr

How to integrate splunk with Hadoop (MapR distribution)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of Splunk documents available on the subject.  The first hits in a Google search will serve you well or go to docs.splunk.com and search for "Hadoop".